# InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable error in Python linuxmint environment

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I test selenium python and I have these errors with firefox and I can't find the solution. Here my code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
options = Options()
options.binary = FirefoxBinary(r'/usr/bin/firefox')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= r'./scrap/geckodriver', options=options) 
driver.get("http://www.google.com") 
print (driver.page_source.encode('utf-8') )
driver.close()
```

My error message python linuxmint :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

I've been searching the forum for a few days, but I can't find a solution for linux mint.

Comment: Did you download geckodriver binary? Did you unpack/saved it? Did you specify the correct path to it, as indicated in my response?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `options.binary = FirefoxBinary()` you can use the [**binary_location**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.binary_location) option as follows:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'/usr/bin/firefox'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of working selenium/Firefox setup on Debian, which should also work on Mint, given it's essentially the same os:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

# firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
# firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver') ## path where you saved geckodriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)
```

Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: not working for me, any idea?

Comment: @M.Mariscal, things changed since last year. The answer was correct when posted. If you have a particular question, post it.